# Which method I can use in Java for configuration file?

Tags: java, configuration, configuration-files

Which method I can use in Java for configuration files, to read and write specific lines and strings? For example (config.ini):

```
mysql_host: localhost
mysql_user: user
```

or

```
mysql_host = localhost
mysql_user = user
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Java Properties](http://ttps://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html):

> Properties are configuration values managed as key/value pairs. In
>   each pair, the key and value are both String values. The key
>   identifies, and is used to retrieve, the value, much as a variable
>   name is used to retrieve the variable's value. For example, an
>   application capable of downloading files might use a property named
>   "download.lastDirectory" to keep track of the directory used for the
>   last download.
>
> To manage properties, create instances of java.util.Properties. This
>   class provides methods for the following:
>
> - loading key/value pairs into a Properties object from a stream,
> - retrieving a value from its key,
> - listing the keys and their values,
> - enumerating over the keys,
> - and saving the properties to a stream.

You can load properties files with

```
Properties applicationProps = new Properties();
try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("appProperties")) {
    applicationProps.load(in);
}
```

and store them with

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("appProperties")) {
    applicationProps.store(out, "---No Comment---");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/) library.

```
Ini ini = new Ini(new File(filename));
java.util.prefs.Preferences prefs = new IniPreferences(ini);
```

And then you can go ahead fetch nodes with `prefs.node("mysql_host")`.